# Randomise References between Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to randomise a consisting data set in MySQL. Data looks like this:

```
|---------|--------|
|Column 1 |Column 2|
|---------|--------|
|   A     |   1    |
|---------|--------|
|   B     |   2    |
|---------|--------|
|   C     |   3    |
|---------|--------|
```

... and should look like this after Shuffling them:

```
|---------|--------|
|Column 1 |Column 2|
|---------|--------|
|   C     |   2    |
|---------|--------|
|   A     |   3    |
|---------|--------|
|   B     |   1    |
|---------|--------|
```

Is there a simple function for doing that? Only found RAND(), but selecting them in random order with existing ("Real") reference is not enough in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a random ordering, C will sometimes be 3. Is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) rn FROM src_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) rn FROM src_table )
SELECT cte1.column1, cte2.column2
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 USING (rn)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00be98bf95b6e9c76084c60fabeae79b)

Each column values are randomly enumerated separately, then the values are combined back into pairs by these random numbers.